# Android list view row highlight with getChildAt()

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in android with 24 items, 7 of which are visible when the activity starts. I would like to be able to highlight the background of any clicked row, while unhighlighting the previously selected row. Here is what I have so far:

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int newPosition, long id) {

       selectedView(oldPosition).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       oldPosition = newPosition
       selectedView(newPosition).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.selected)
}

 public View selectedView(int selection){
    View selectedView = listview.getChildAt(selection);

    return selectedView;
}
```

This is working great! But only for the first 7 rows... When I attempt to click rows that were once off the screen, getChildAt() returns null. I know that getChildAt(i) gets the view of visible rows only, but once the view becomes visible it returns null. What do I need to do to tell the app the listview item is now visible? I am also interested in any other caveats you see with the implementation.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `selectedView(newPosition).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.selected)` with `view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.selected)`?

Comment: hmm that solved the newly visible row from returning null, but it isn't unhighlighting the previously selected view that's off the screen